# Dropdown navbar complication

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

i dont know where it goes wrong but everything i try isnt getting my dropdown to close 
and stays a big block. 
anyone can show me what i do wrong so i can remind the problem and what i did wrong in the first place?

i tried to rework it all but cant figure out how i get in to drop down insted of staying open like that.

```css
body       {font-family:'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            padding:20px 50px 150px;
            font-size:13px;
            text-align:center;
            background:#666;}

.navbar a   {text-decoration:none;
            color:#FF0004}
 


.navbar ul         {text-align:left; 
                display:inline;
                   margin:0px;
                   padding:15px 4px 17px 0;
                   list-style:none;
                   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                   box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);}


.navbar ul li      {font:bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
                   display:inline-block;
                   margin-right:-4px;
                   postion:relative;
                   padding:15px 20px;
                   background:#fff;
                   cursor:pointer;
                   -webkit-transition:all 0.2s;
                   -moz-transition:all 0.2s;
                   -ms-transition:all 0.2s;
                   -o-transition:all 0.2s;
                   transition:all 0.2s;}


.navbar ul li:hover {background:#555;
                    color:#FFF;}


.navbar ul li ul    {padding:0;
                    postion:absolute;
                    top:48px;
                    left:0;
                    width:150px;
                    visibility:hidden;
                    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s;
                    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s;
                    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s;
                    -transition:opacity 0.2s;}

.navbar ul li ul li {backgound:#555;
                    display:block;
                    color:#FFF;
                    text-shadow:0 -01px 0 #000;}

.navbar li ul li:hover {backgound:#666;}

.navbar ul li ul li:hover ul {display:block;
                             opacity: 1;
                             visibility:visible;
                             }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="recepten.html">Recepten</a>
           <ul>
      <li><a href="lactosevrij.html">Lactosevrij</a></li>
      <li><a href="suikervrij.html">Suikervrij</a></li>
      <li><a href="glutenvrij.html">Glutenvrij</a></li>
           </ul></li>
    <li><a href="abonneren.html">Abonneren</a>
           <ul>
      <li><a href="basis.html">Basis</a></li>
      <li><a href="standaard.html">Standaard</a></li>
      <li><a href="luxe.html">Luxe</a></li>
           </ul></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: You need some javascript to get it right

Comment: as far i know javascript isnt needed to make it work

Comment: to hide the dropdown you can set CSS  .navbar li > ul { display: none;} . Please, describe when it should appear and hide again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some typos and also targeting the wrong ul.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #666;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF0004
}

.navbar ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.navbar ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  /*position typo */
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #FFF;
}

.navbar ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*position typo */
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.navbar ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 -01px 0 #000;
}

.navbar li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}


/* i refactored this selector */

.navbar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="recepten.html">Recepten</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="lactosevrij.html">Lactosevrij</a></li>
        <li><a href="suikervrij.html">Suikervrij</a></li>
        <li><a href="glutenvrij.html">Glutenvrij</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="abonneren.html">Abonneren</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="basis.html">Basis</a></li>
        <li><a href="standaard.html">Standaard</a></li>
        <li><a href="luxe.html">Luxe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how did u noticed it so fast? and where did i targeted it to the wrong one ? just wanna see where so i know what i did wrong BIG THNX btw !

Comment: gonna place them next to eachother to see if i can spot the mistakes THNX

Comment: I have added comments. If you use a code editor, it should highlight it e.g VS Code should find it out by default.

Comment: ahh i did .navbar ul li ul li:hover ul , instead of ul li:hover ul guess i gotta checkout the VS code

Comment: one more question haha , now i wanna try to give another color to the link tekst when i hover above it cause i had that before i added the none tekst decoration on the <a> selector for the link, but because of that i have to give the <a> a color ,but it cinda working agains my hover color

Comment: @Webdesignerinclass, you need to modify your HTML to incorporate some classes which will make it easier to target the elements and to make a better menu.  http://flukeout.github.io/ is a nice playground to polish selector skills. I hope it would help you :)

Comment: yea i gotta get more into it , just started the school for 4 months so im trying hard to get into it and to pass the schooling , gotta say i have more help here than they are giving so really thankfull for ur help and the others help who are given, makes me see what i did wrong and how its better to do so thnks !!